# How to compare two columns in a dataframe with a function and for loop?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have two columns floors and floor total

```
df = pd.DataFrame({"floor": [1,2,30], "floors_total": [1, 50, 30]})
```

I want to write a function such as if in a row both values in floors total and floor are equal then return "last floor" and then if floor = 1 then return "first floor" and if other return "other"
I want to apply this to df

I am trying to write a for loop which is :

```
def new(df):
  a = "floor"
  b = "floors_total"
  for a,b in df.iteritems():
    if a == b:
      return "last floor"
    elif a == 1:
      return "first floor"
    else:
      return "other"
df["floor_postiton"] = df.apply(new)
```

I am getting all rows in the new column as NaN

Comment: Please follow the [guidelines](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) to ask a proper question on the forum

Comment: What is the reason to use a (slow) iteration instead of the vectorized pandas or numpy methods?

Comment: No reason. I have not yet learnt vectorized pandas or numpy methods. Is there faster way with numpy code?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can avoid the (slow) iteration over the dataframe with `np.where`:

```
df['floor_position'] = np.where(df['floor'] == df['floors_total'],
                'last floor',
                np.where(df['floor'] == 1, 'first floor',
                     'other'))
```